# Get the next element in Linked List with a condition

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm using a Linked List for turn management in my game. I  have Players which I iterate through them, however when one player completes the game he needs to be skipped over, which is where I'm failing at.

How can I do this? here is what I have right now:

```
public Player GetNextPlayer() {
        var current = linkedPlayerList.Find(currentPlayer);

        Player nextPlayer = current.Next == null ? linkedPlayerList.First.Value : current.Next.Value;

        SetCurrentPlayer(nextPlayer);
        return nextPlayer;
}
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
Player nextPlayer = current.Next == null
   ? linkedPlayerList.First(f => !f.RoundCompleted)
   : current.Next.List.Where(w=>!w.RoundCompleted).ElementAt(linkedPlayerList.ToList().IndexOf(currentPlayer));
```

Comment: You need to explain why it doesn't work. What output do you get?

Comment: Why don't you just use an array with an index to indicate who's turn it is?  Why use a linked list?

Comment: pressing in code into one statement is mostly not a good idea, it makes it more difficult to read, instead write code for people and let the optimizer handle the optimization.

Comment: It doesn't return the next player. Unity crashes when I breakpoint so can't debug.

I preferred using LinkedList to improve readability and even with arrays we would need to find the next player who's round wasn't completed.

Comment: I'm not sure a linked list is the correct data type here if you need to do linear searching.

Comment: @juharr I know Linked List performs slower than List but I don't think it will matter too much in this case. Besides the reason why I went with Linked List in the first place is readability, compared to constantly having to deal with indexes of a List to iterate through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a loop to check for your condition. Comments in code to explain.

```
LinkedList<Player> linkedPlayerList = ......;
Player currentPlayer = .......;

public Player GetNextPlayer()
{
    // Find the current node
    var curNode = linkedPlayerList.Find(currentPlayer);

    // Point to the next
    LinkedListNode<Player> nextNode = curNode.Next;

    // Check if at the end of the list
    nextNode = nextNode == null ? linkedPlayerList.First : nextNode;    

    // Loop stops when we find the condition true or we reach the starting point
    while (curNode != nextNode)
    {
        // Exit if found....
        if (!nextNode.Value.RoundCompleted)
            break;
        // Manage the next node to check for....
        nextNode = nextNode?.Next == null ? linkedPlayerList.First : nextNode.Next;    
    }
    SetCurrentPlayer(nextNode.Value);
    return nextNode.Value;
}
```

Comment: Works really well. Minus the null propagation which I can't do in Unity since it still uses the Net 3.5.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (add an an extra null check on next):

```
Player nextPlayer = current.Next.List.FirstOrDefault (x => !.RoundCompleted);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working. It always picks the first Player.